# App not active running a job, how to do that?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Hello guys i saw **google plus** iphone app uploading my images without the app being active or in background it is closed completely! how i can run a process like this in my app

Comment: not possible, see answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mistaken. This doesn't happen. The app uploads your photos when you tap it and continues in the background for 10 minutes once the app has been exited using the home button using

```
- (UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier)beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:(void (^)(void))handler
```

Google even say this is what happens in [their instant upload FAQ](http://support.google.com/plus/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2453873):

> Note: Photos and videos will upload while the Google+ application is
>   open and for a brief period of time afterwards.

What you want, the ability to run code

> "without the app being active or in background it is closed
>   completely!"

is not possible on iOS

Comment: No, iam sure it uploads my photos without open it, you can try it

Comment: i've added proof to my answer.